# To get image id from grid view android

Tags: java, android

I am designing a password system based on images which are displayed in the grid view. Since I am not so much familiar with android I want your help.My images are displayed dynamically on the grid i.e they keep on changing their position.
i am not to figure out how to define image as password.I want four images to be clicked in order and save them at the time of registration to the user.I am having difficulty in the saving part like which method to use and where to save.

what i want to do is this.
I want phone to display 15 images dynamically in grid view. then the user clicks 4 images in sequence to set the pass code for registration and it is saved offline. so the user next time clicks 4 images in same order to get unlocked. I am having difficulty in storing the corresponding image displayed on the particular grid because in need images to save the pass code and how to store the data of the user like username, name , and the images which he has clicked.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: what i want to do is this.
I want phone to display 15 images dynamically in grid view. then the user clicks 4 images in sequence to set the pass code for registration and it is saved offline. so the user next time clicks 4 images in same order to get unlocked. I am having difficulty in getting the corresponding image displayed on the particular grid and how to store the data of the user like username, name , and the images which he has clicked.

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ImageButton's in your Gridlayout or use a button and set the image as background.Further write a adapter class(I am assuming that you have written one).
Set OnClick listener inside adapter and listen to the same click..

In your adapter class

```
 holder.buttonone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((GridView)parent).performItemClick(v,position,0);

        }
    });
 holder.buttontwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((GridView)parent).performItemClick(v,position,0);

        }
    });//further for your 15 buttons
```

And in your activity:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int        position, long id) {
           switch(view.getId)
        {
         case R.id.buttonone:
           //set the code in your edittext
           break; 
         case R.id.buttontwo:
           //do your stuff 
            break;
            }
    });
```

I am assuming you have a textview/edittext that will print the passcode or atleast xxxx ..So you can display it there and further handle that data.
Use `edittext.getText().toString()` and store it.
Hope that helps